# Can't run Spring Boot application after packaging it with Environment Variables

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm doing a Spring Boot Tutorial where i created a REST API for a Postgres DB which runs inside a Docker container.

When i run the application with IntelliJ everything works fine and i can get the values from the DB with Postman.

When i package the application with Maven and run it inside the terminal with the command:

```
java -jar .\conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

i get the following output:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

2022-09-07 15:45:19.223  INFO 25004 --- [           main] c.p.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : Starting ConferenceDemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 18.0.2.1 on EX420 with PID 25004 (C:\dev\downloads\conference-demo\conference-demo\target\conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by grpi in C:\dev\downloads\conference-demo\conference-demo\target)
2022-09-07 15:45:19.225  INFO 25004 --- [           main] c.p.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-09-07 15:45:19.778  INFO 25004 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-07 15:45:19.835  INFO 25004 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 43 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-09-07 15:45:20.172  INFO 25004 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log               : Logging initialized @1749ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2022-09-07 15:45:20.329  INFO 25004 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyServletWebServerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2022-09-07 15:45:20.331  INFO 25004 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : jetty-9.4.48.v20220622; built: 2022-06-21T20:42:25.880Z; git: 6b67c5719d1f4371b33655ff2d047d24e171e49a; jvm 18.0.2.1+1-1
2022-09-07 15:45:20.360  INFO 25004 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler.application     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-09-07 15:45:20.361  INFO 25004 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1088 ms
2022-09-07 15:45:20.443  INFO 25004 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2022-09-07 15:45:20.443  INFO 25004 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2022-09-07 15:45:20.445  INFO 25004 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2022-09-07 15:45:20.457  INFO 25004 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@3e7dd664{application,/,[file:///C:/Users/grpi/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.8080.14230885857400953126/],AVAILABLE}
2022-09-07 15:45:20.458  INFO 25004 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : Started @2036ms
2022-09-07 15:45:20.474  WARN 25004 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDepe
ndencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependenc
y expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [or
g/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2022-09-07 15:45:20.478  INFO 25004 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : node0 Stopped scavenging
2022-09-07 15:45:20.481  INFO 25004 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Stopped o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@3e7dd664{application,/,[file:///C:/Users/grpi/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.8080.14230885857400953126/],STOPPED}
2022-09-07 15:45:20.489  INFO 25004 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-07 15:45:20.512 ERROR 25004 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitiali
zationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with nam
e 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at com.pluralsight.conferencedemo.ConferenceDemoApplication.main(ConferenceDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean i
nstantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(DatabaseDriver.java:290) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
app.version=1.0.0
```

I have set the the Database URL, user and password as Environment Variables:
[image: Environment variables]

After removing the environment variables and hardcoding the URL, user and password inside the properties file the running after packaging works again.

When i run:

```
  String output = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL");
  System.out.println(output);
```

The output is:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/conference_app
```

So the variables seem to work.

Could anyone explain this to me please and tell me how to run the jar with environment variables without hardcoding the data?

Comment: I think, You just confuse (real.."system environment" in your screenshot ) system variables with those of an "intellij runtime/debug configuration". The variables must be available in the system/shell, where you `java -jar .\conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Comment: ..in windows: `SET FOO=bar` in "unix-based": `export FOO=bar` resp. `setenv FOO bar`

Comment: I missunderstood the variables. Thank you for claryfing it.
I set the variables in the shell now. Here's a part of the output of the 'set' command: https://ibb.co/3S5qbXK
However there are still errors: https://pastebin.com/MaywvmCP

Comment: `URL must start with 'jdbc'..` ..seems still wrong env variable!

Comment: Maybe i wrote it poorly to understand sorry but only the database is running inside a docker container.
The application itself is not.
I'm really clueless atm :/ 
Either im doing something wrong or im missing something important.
But as you can see the variables are there (according to the 'set command' output.)
It's just weird..

Comment: stop! :) (no, i read poorly:) Plese try: just comment out (`#`) in your application.properties the three `spring.datasource.*` entries...because: You chose already correct variable names + [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding)

Comment: esp. [relaxed-binding.environment-variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables)

Comment: Still not working :/
https://pastebin.com/x8KRuHSZ
But thank you!

Comment: I mean i could write the database connection data inside a config class. Then its working. But as far as i understood in some cases it's better to not have them inside the code. That's what im trying to achieve. That's a reasonable approach, isn't it? I really don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run your application jar with `java` command, you should define your system properties manually like below:

```
java -jar .\conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=xx \
  -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=xx \
  -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=xx
```

BTW: If you want to run app with Docker, Just add some `ENV` variables in your Dockerfile. see details fo [Docker Env](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement)

Comment: I tried your solution. However the errors are still there:
https://pastebin.com/F7QptDW3

Comment: Can you show me the really comand that you ran.

Comment: The Exact command i ran copied from terminal:
`java -jar .\conference-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \ -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/conference_app \ -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres \ -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=Welcome
`